# curl can't connect; wget can

Tags: wget, curl

trying to connect to my script on a remote server with `curl` but:

```
col-pos-spd# curl -v http://***:80/monitor/reply.php
* About to connect() to *** port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 83.xxx.xxx.2... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

then i tried `wget` and:

```
wget -v http://***/monitor/reply.php
--2011-09-22 12:29:07--  http://***/monitor/reply.php
Connecting to 83.xxx.xxx.2:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 8 [text/html]
Saving to: `reply.php'

100%[====================================================================================================================>] 8           --.-K/s   in 0s

2011-09-22 12:29:07 (1.05 MB/s) - `reply.php' saved [8/8]
```

so i can't figure out whi i'm getting an error with `curl`and how can i avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

wget may be using a proxy setting whilst curl isn't - check your environment variables (http_proxy?) and startup files.

you can test this with

```
wget --proxy=off …
```

[wget 1.13](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Proxies) checks environment variables `http_proxy, ftp_proxy, no_proxy`
[curl 7.22](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html) checks environment variables `http_proxy, HTTPS_PROXY, FTP_PROXY, GOPHER_PROXY, ALL_PROXY, NO_PROXY`

wget can read these settings from `~/.wgetrc`
curl can read these settings from `~/.curlrc`

Comment: thaks! but i've got a problem: `http_proxy` is undefined and `/usr/local/etc/wgetrc` is empty. where can `wget` store it's settings?

Comment: @k102: In your home directory (that's what `~/` means) in a file named `.wgetrc` - remember that `ls` won't show it without the `-a` option.

Comment: there's no such file (`ls -a` and `ls -all`)...

Answer (score -1):

I've got the same problem, and I just solved it!
The answer is to open the PSAV mode, because the curl  use the PORT mode for ftp as default.
use it like this:

```
curl --ftp-port 21  ftp://your.address
```