# Curl local host names on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: localhost, curl, hosts-file, osx-yosemite

I just upgraded from Mavericks to Yosemite, and now `curl` can't see loopback host names.

Set up a simple http server to test:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

Now I can hit localhost:8000 in chrome.  I can even wget it.  But in curl, this happens:

```
$ curl localhost:8000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused
```

However, this works:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:8000
```

I read [this answer about wget proxy settings](https://superuser.com/questions/338528/curl-cant-connect-wget-can), but it didn't help, because this works:

```
$ wget --proxy=off localhost:8000
```

This is really frustrating, because I have a few different loopback hostnames listed in my `/etc/hosts` file so I can develop apps locally, and I'm used to debugging them with curl.

I've tried with the version of curl that ships with osx:

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.37.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0) libcurl/7.37.1 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz

$ curl localhost:8000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused

$ curl 127.0.0.1 # works
```

And I've tried compiling curl with brew:

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.38.0/bin/curl --version
curl 7.38.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0) libcurl/7.38.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz

$ /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.38.0/bin/curl localhost:8000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused

$ /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.38.0/bin/curl 127.0.0.1:8000 # works
```

Comment: I ran into a similar problem testing a node.js application. I saw that node's debugging said it was binding to 0.0.0.0, and tried 'curl -4 http://localhost...' and it worked, but without the -4 it failed. It appears the IPv6 address is being resolved out of /etc/hosts before the IPv4 one.

Comment: I'm having the same issue you've described Nick.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I just got it to work by commenting out one of the IPv6 loopback lines from my /etc/hosts file:

```
#fe80::1%lo0    localhost
```

Now all of my loopback hostnames work, not just localhost. I wonder what's up with this?

Comment: I had that and it helped me as well. I don't know what's the deal with that line; it seeems my system had it from before Yosemite.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wonder though, why at the core it favors the IPv6 for the loopback device over the IPv4. This only started happening for me on Yosemite.

Answer (score 25):

Alternative **(does not require sudo or modifying `/etc/hosts`)** -
always use ipv4 until curl gets smarter.

```
$ echo '--ipv4' >> ~/.curlrc
```

(then everything will work as desired)

Comment: Thanks — this problem was driving me nuts, but your solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `0.0.0.0` is a special address meaning "any IPv4 address".

A socket can be bound to either IPv4 or IPv6 protocol. If a socket is bound to `0.0.0.0`, that means it will listen to any IPv4 trying to connect to it, and will be represented as it follows:

```
$ nc -l 0.0.0.0 8085
$ lsof -i4 -Pnl | grep 8085
  nc        23994 [xxx]    3u  IPv4 [xxx]      0t0  TCP *:8085 (LISTEN)
```

The `*` sign is equivalent to `0.0.0.0` on IPv4.

For IPv6:

```
$ nc -l :: 8085
$ lsof -i6 -Pnl | grep 8085
  nc        24145 [xxx]    3u  IPv6 [xxx]      0t0  TCP *:8085 (LISTEN)
```

The `*` sign is equivalent to `::` on IPv6, [as in the official specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5156).

The reason is that `curl` tries to resolve to a random `localhost` entry in `/etc/hosts`, and as @NickRetallack mentioned, that entry is the chosen one by `curl` when resolving `localhost` in its default mode (assumedly IPv6 or IPv4, whatever resolves first).

Forcing it in `--ipv4` mode, as @CharlesHebdough suggested, will make `curl` resolve `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` (assuming there are no other IPv4 entries for `localhost` in `/etc/hosts`).

Each implementation will resolve `localhost` as they wish, hence why you had intermittent success with different tools.

To be the most precise possible, use `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost, but it will bound you to IPv4. `localhost` gives you the flexibility to work in both IPv6 and IPv4 protocols, however in some implementations you might have trouble, as in that specific version of `curl`.