# Why does curl and wget take so long to resolve locally mapped DNS on OSX?

Tags: macos, dns, wget, curl

I work with a team to develop a web service and client, each of us, of course, working on our own machines.  To keep things simple and more consistent, we use similar domains in the code and update `/etc/hosts` to resolve those domains to localhost.

1. works fine for my web browser; response times are snappy
2. curl and wget take ~4 seconds to resolve DNS before successfully completing the request

I did find the `--resolve` flag for curl which [resolves the delay](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33121/curl-resolve-appears-to-do-nothing/33123#33123?newreg=95302019af7e4536bf34b3b918d668ab), but I could just as well use `127.0.0.1` and define the headers necessary to get the same effect.

with flag (and updated `/etc/hosts` file)

```
# /etc/hosts
...
127.0.0.1 mp-api.example.local
```

command

```
curl -k -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_connect}:%{time_starttransfer}:%{time_total}\\n \
  --resolve mp-api.example.local:8094:127.0.0.1 \
  -H 'Host: mp-api.example.local:8094' \
  'https://mp-api.example.local:8094/api/categories/tree.json'
```

with 127.0.0.1

```
curl -k -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_connect}:%{time_starttransfer}:%{time_total}\\n \
  -H 'Host: mp-api.example.local:8094' \
  'https://127.0.0.1:8094/api/categories/tree.json'
```

What are some of the reasons for the delay in DNS resolution for tools like `curl` and `wget`?  And what are some effective ways of troubleshooting that delay?

Answer (score 1):

Per suggestion that there might be settings in the Network tool, I found the values in "Bypass proxy settings..." interesting.

[image]

It would appear that I have been having problems with DNS resolution for curl and wget because I have been using a domain ending with `.local`.  Perhaps it's essentially a reserved value.

So I changed my settings so I now use a domain ending with `.loc` and all is well again -- no more 4 seconds off in la-la land waiting for DNS resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Check /etc/nsswitch.conf file

There configuration how names to id converted.
One of lines for hostnames:

```
hosts:      files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname mymachines
```

Ensure, "files" on first place.

UPD.

[Curl local host names on Mac OS X Yosemite](https://superuser.com/questions/830920/curl-local-host-names-on-mac-os-x-yosemite)

look like curl take responsibility for name resolving and prefer ipv6

try add --ipv4 key or add ipv6 to hosts

Comment: Does a service need to be recycled to pick up changes?  `/etc/nsswitch.conf` doesn't exist on my computer.  I added it, supplied with the values you suggested, but I'm still getting a 4 sec delay on curl and wget requests.  Browser requests do not experience the same delay.

Comment: strange it not exists. AFAIK nss is part of glib.
Try strace curl ...
What distro you use?

Comment: I'm on Mac OS (El Capitan); I don't have `strace` in my path, so I can't run that command.

```
curl --version
curl 7.43.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0) libcurl/7.43.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets
```

I installed with `brew`.

Comment: Sorry. I implied it Linux based. I added tag and note to question.